# Верхняя панель Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Народ кто с Xamarin Forms работал кому-нибудь удавалось убрать или видоизменить эту панель верхнюю?
Это вообще реализуемо?[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Если бы это было нереализуемо, то все бы приложения под Xamarin выглядели одинаково - не находите это странным? Для начала укажите способ, с помощью которого вы создали приложение, на основе какого шаблона и как именно вы хотите видоизменить эту панель.

Answer (score 0):

Эта *верхняя панель* называется **NavigationBar**. Чтобы убрать, пропиши в *файле разметки* своей страницы (**.xaml**) свойство HasNavigationBar = false

```
<ContentPage 
         ...
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```

Должно работать.